# Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit an exponential curve to data

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

Using curve_fit() to fit an exponential function to two data sets gives a result that only fits a few of the points. It seems to obtain the best R squared value, so is there anything I can do?

So I have two small data sets to which I want to fit a function. The function is exponential in nature, so I am trying to fit a model function `exp(a*x + b)` to the data using `curve_fit()`. In essence, the main block of my code is the following:

```py
popt_1, pcov_1 = curve_fit(model_f, x, y1, p0=[0.05,6])
popt_2, pcov_2 = curve_fit(model_f, x, y2, p0=[0.05,6])
a1_opt, b1_opt = popt_1
a2_opt, b1_opt = popt_2
x_model = np.linspace(25, 300, 100)
y1_model = model_f(x_model, a1_opt, b1_opt)
y2_model = model_f(x_model, a2_opt, b1_opt)
```

I also calculate R squared, and the value of it, as well as a_1 and b_1, are:
R^2 = 099679..., a_1 = 0.025055... and b_1 = 9.021441...
Below is a plot of the points and the fit. As you can see, the fit seems really bad. Am I missing some parameters which I could give to the curve_fit() function?

[image: Plot of the data points and corresponding fits]

It seems to me as if the fit is prioritizing the values with higher y and x. Is this related to the fact that in absolute terms, the square differences between the fit and the actual points for higher y-values affect R squared more, than the squared differences for lower y-values? If so, wouldn't this be a regular issue with exponential functions?

I found a way to circumvent this issue, but I wanted to ask here if there is something I should do differently to obtain a better fit. The solution (it seems), is to take a log of my y-values, and fit a linear model to these values. Then I simply take the obtained model parameter values, obtain y_model, and then plot the fit using logarithmic yscale. Below a plot of the results.

[image: Plot of the data points and another fit]

For this fit, I obtain the following values:
R^2 = 0.99057..., a_1 = 0.0351598... and b_1 = 11.638803....
The R squared is not as good, but at least now the fit represents the whole data set, unlike the first fit. Or should one always take the fit with the best R squared value, even if the results are like shown here?

Hopefully, someone can offer me some insights, and as this is my first post, I apologize if there are mistakes in the way I presented my issue.

Comment: How is the fit used in real life? Only this can dictate whether a log fit is appropriate or not.

Comment: There's a clear sigmoid component in the function. Are you married to the existing model or can it be replaced?

Comment: Can you show your data?

Comment: @j.hed You are on the right track `the fit is prioritizing the values with higher y and x`. Higher x do not matter, the fit is minimizing least squares and the relative magnitude between your largest y values to the lowest y values means that it will favor parameters where the discrepancy is small for the largest y values (as they contribute the most to the error). Taking a log "closes the gap" between the high and low y values,e.g. the range of values they take is much smaller and it acts as weighting up the low values compared to the high ones. Now least square wants less discrepancy there.

Comment: Apologies for the long wait for my reply. @Reinderien, we expect a logarithmic fit for the data from prior knowledge. But, "Learning is a mess" made it clearer for me, I suppose it is, in some cases, better to take a log first, and then fit, than fit an exponential function. Thanks!

Comment: What about fitting a sigma? It will be more accurate.